# Can I update my php database for output from different pages?

Tags: php, mysql

I store data of users in a block-wise procedure in my mySQL database. Specifically, they do a task on page 1, I store the data in database 1, they do another part of the task on page 2, I store that in database 2, etc. So afterwards, I need to structure these data back together (with R). This is is sometimes tricky because some complete not all blocks, so I am looking for a way to make this at least more straightforward for each user's data.

This is how my php script looks like in principle:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = ip2long($ipaddress);
$unid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['UNID']);
$condition = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['CONDITION']);
$counterbal = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['COUNTERBALANCING']);
$attempts = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ATTEMPTS']);


$sql="INSERT INTO `mypage_databaseA`.`database1` (`unid`, `ip`, `condition`, `counterbal`, `attempts`) 
VALUES ('$unid', '$ip', '$condition', '$counterbal', '$attempts')";
```

What I'd like to achieve is that I but all data of, say, user 1 into the same database and attach it to the same variables. For example, if the output variable `attempts` is 1,2,3 for block1 and 4,5,6 for block2, I like to have one database where after two blocks, `attempts` is 1,2,3,4,5,6. How can I do that with my php script?

Comment: don't use multiple databases use multiple tables, one table for each section, store against each record a user id and create a users table. then you can retrieve all your data back in a single query which would be a join

Comment: @Dave Thanks for this hint. I do actually have it in tables form, I edited my post. I am new to MySQL and mainly retrieve my data without any problems. But this block-wise procedure gives me troubles with the JOIN now. I have asked that in another post.